# Seed Method AddOrUpdate Crashes Visual Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

My seed method works fine when using AddOrUpdate on other tables, this code specifically however crashes Visual Studio each time it is run.

```
context.GoogleCategories.AddOrUpdate(
    p => p.ID,
    new GoogleCategory { ParentID = null, name = "Clothing & Accessories" }
);
```

Here is the model definition:

```
[Table("GoogleCategory")]
public class GoogleCategory
{
    public GoogleCategory()
    {
        this.Parent = new GoogleCategory();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual GoogleCategory Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And what is created in the migration:

```
CreateTable("dbo.GoogleCategory",
    c => new
    {
        ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
        name = c.String(),
        ParentID = c.Int(),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.GoogleCategory", t => t.ParentID)
    .Index(t => t.ParentID);
```

Any ideas? There is an Event Viewer log but it shows no notable information I can see.

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61219.0, time stamp: 0x55cdaf21
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34209, time stamp: 0x5348961e
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x001a149e
Faulting process id: 0x1b48
Faulting application start time: 0x01d10b10520f2a40
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 8b926474-7706-11e5-aaf4-0024810b020a
```

Comment: try breaking on all exceptions, maybe you can break before VS crashes

Comment: Does it crash your application, or Visual Studio itself? The latter seems like a machine problem. Did you perform a memory test, verify all updates are installed, and so on?

Comment: @CodeCaster Not sure how you check that, I'll add the Event Viewer log to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post my own answer I should have really looked into it more first.

When creating a GoogleCategory a stack overflow exception was occuring because in the constructor it is trying to create a new GoogleCategory (duh) so that was obviously just spinning and spinning.

That does mean however StackOverflowExceptions in the seed method will crash Visual Studio 2012 rather than reporting an error.